# Trying to flash Ubuntu touch onto my nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Using `phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup` to flash Ubuntu-touch. It removes android and all, but gets to "waiting for recovery image to boot" and just shows a blank screen on the phone. Tried this about 3 times now, and I've waited a good ten minutes each time before giving up and reverting back to android.. Any suggestions are appreciated!